# Adding foreign key constraints in archive tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have these tables and Oldbookings is an archive table containing rows from Bookings made a year ago. Also, assuming that such constraints were already defined in Bookings:

```
FOREIGN KEY (cusNo) REFERENCES Customers(cusNo)
FOREIGN KEY (flightNo) REFERENCES Flights(flightNo)
```

Would it make sense to define these contraints (foreign key) in the archive table OldBooking?

---

Customers(**cusNo**, cusName, DOB)
Flights(**flightNo**, destination)
Bookings(**cusNo**, **flightNo**, date)

OldBookings(**cusNo**, **flightNo**, date)

---

Answer (score 2):

"Duplicating" such constraints in the archive DB would secure you against flaws *in the archival process itself*.

Up to you (or perhaps up to your users) to decide whether or not you want to guard your archives against such flaws.

Answer (score 1):

In the abstract, I'd say don't break the BOOKINGS tables into CURRENT_BOOKINGS and OLD_BOOKINGS.  If you need to subdivide the table, perhaps you could use partitioning to make logical subtables.

If you do need to maintain an off-line or secondary-system history, it's generally not a bad idea to denormalize the OLD_BOOKINGS table to capture the information you need in a flat record structure, like this:

```
**BOOKINGS**
BOOKING_ID
CUSTOMER_ID
FLIGHT_ID
...

**OLD_BOOKINGS**
BOOKING_ID
CUSTOMER_ID
CUSTOMER_COLUMN_1
...
CUSTOMER_COLUMN_N
FLIGHT_ID
FLIGHT_COLUMN_1
...
FLIGHT_COLUMN_N
BOOKING_ATTRIBUTE_1
...
BOOKING_ATTRIBUTE_N
```

Comment: However, sometimes BOOKINGS and OLDBOOKINGS are stored in separate databases, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I'm an Oracle guy, so I don't know that what you mean by "different databases" is what I hear when you say "different databases."  I do think if you're going to store OLD_BOOKINGS away from CURRENT_BOOKINGS, you should probably not have both referencing the same FLIGHT and CUSTOMER tables, which means you should denormalize OLD_BOOKINGS or you have to replicate those the FLIGHT and CUSTOMER tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the business requirements.

The presence of an OldBookings row referencing a flight or customer would not allow that flight or customer to be deleted or moved.  It ensures that OldBookings references a valid flight and customer.